# Apache Spark: network errors between executors

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm running Apache Spark 1.3.1 on Scala 2.11.2, and when running on an HPC cluster with large enough data, I get numerous errors like the ones at the bottom of my post (repeated multiple times per second, until the job gets killed for being over time). Based on the errors, the executor is attempting to get shuffle data from other nodes but is unable to do so.

This same program executes fine with either (a) a smaller amount of data, or (b) in local-only mode, so it has something to do with the data getting sent over the network (and isn't triggered with a very small amount of data).

The code that is being executed around the time this happens is as follows:

```scala
val partitioned_data = data  // data was read as sc.textFile(inputFile)
  .zipWithIndex.map(x => (x._2, x._1))
  .partitionBy(partitioner)  // A custom partitioner
  .map(_._2)

// Force previous lazy operations to be evaluated. Presumably adds some
// overhead, but hopefully the minimum possible...
// Suggested on Spark user list: http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Forcing-RDD-computation-with-something-else-than-count-td707.html
sc.runJob(partitioned_data, (iter: Iterator[_]) => {})
```

Is this indicative of a bug, or is there something I'm doing wrong?

Here's a small snippet of the stderr log of one of the executors (full log is [here](http://pastebin.com/tH830ELb)):

```
15/04/21 14:59:28 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error sending result ChunkFetchSuccess{streamChunkId=StreamChunkId{streamId=1601401593000, chunkIndex=0}, buffer=FileSegmentManagedBuffer{file=/tmp/spark-0f8d0598-b137-4d14-993a-568b2ab3709a/spark-12d5ff0a-2793-4b76-8a0b-d977a5924925/spark-7ad9382d-05cf-49d4-9a52-d42e6ca7117d/blockmgr-b72d4068-d065-47e6-8a10-867f723000db/15/shuffle_0_1_0.data, offset=26501223, length=6227612}} to /10.0.0.5:41160; closing connection
java.io.IOException: Resource temporarily unavailable
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferToDirectly(FileChannelImpl.java:415)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo(FileChannelImpl.java:516)
    at org.apache.spark.network.buffer.LazyFileRegion.transferTo(LazyFileRegion.java:96)
    at org.apache.spark.network.protocol.MessageWithHeader.transferTo(MessageWithHeader.java:89)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWriteFileRegion(NioSocketChannel.java:237)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel.doWrite(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:233)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:264)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:707)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:315)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:676)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1059)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:688)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:669)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:115)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:688)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:718)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:706)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:741)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:895)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:240)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.respond(TransportRequestHandler.java:147)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processFetchRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:119)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:91)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:44)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:130)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
15/04/21 14:59:28 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error sending result ChunkFetchSuccess{streamChunkId=StreamChunkId{streamId=1601401593000, chunkIndex=1}, buffer=FileSegmentManagedBuffer{file=/tmp/spark-0f8d0598-b137-4d14-993a-568b2ab3709a/spark-12d5ff0a-2793-4b76-8a0b-d977a5924925/spark-7ad9382d-05cf-49d4-9a52-d42e6ca7117d/blockmgr-b72d4068-d065-47e6-8a10-867f723000db/27/shuffle_0_5_0.data, offset=3792987, length=2862285}} to /10.0.0.5:41160; closing connection
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
15/04/21 14:59:28 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error sending result ChunkFetchSuccess{streamChunkId=StreamChunkId{streamId=1601401593002, chunkIndex=0}, buffer=FileSegmentManagedBuffer{file=/tmp/spark-0f8d0598-b137-4d14-993a-568b2ab3709a/spark-12d5ff0a-2793-4b76-8a0b-d977a5924925/spark-7ad9382d-05cf-49d4-9a52-d42e6ca7117d/blockmgr-b72d4068-d065-47e6-8a10-867f723000db/15/shuffle_0_1_0.data, offset=0, length=10993212}} to /10.0.0.6:42426; closing connection
java.io.IOException: Resource temporarily unavailable
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferToDirectly(FileChannelImpl.java:415)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo(FileChannelImpl.java:516)
    at org.apache.spark.network.buffer.LazyFileRegion.transferTo(LazyFileRegion.java:96)
    at org.apache.spark.network.protocol.MessageWithHeader.transferTo(MessageWithHeader.java:89)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWriteFileRegion(NioSocketChannel.java:237)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel.doWrite(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:233)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:264)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:707)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:315)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:676)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1059)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:688)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:669)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:115)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:688)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:718)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:706)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:741)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:895)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:240)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.respond(TransportRequestHandler.java:147)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processFetchRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:119)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:91)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:44)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:130)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
15/04/21 14:59:28 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from node5.someuniversity.edu/10.0.0.5:60089
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:21)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:233)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:206)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:236)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledHeapByteBuf.setBytes(PooledHeapByteBuf.java:234)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:225)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
15/04/21 14:59:28 ERROR TransportResponseHandler: Still have 2 requests outstanding when connection from node5.someuniversity.edu/10.0.0.5:60089 is closed
15/04/21 14:59:28 INFO RetryingBlockFetcher: Retrying fetch (1/3) for 2 outstanding blocks after 5000 ms
```

Answer (score 19):

This appears to be a bug related to the `Netty` networking system (block transfer service), added in [Spark 1.2](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-dev/201411.mbox/%3CCABPQxssL04Q+rBLtP-D8W+z3aTn+g-Um6GMdGDnh-hZcvD-c_g@mail.gmail.com%3E). Adding `.set("spark.shuffle.blockTransferService", "nio")` to my SparkConf fixed the bug, so now everything works perfectly.

I found [a post on the spark-user mailing list](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201503.mbox/%3CCAFn+d95xVv4vNz0sX+uH=yM2o6ZvApAA9J5WE_r=JC6siXHj-Q@mail.gmail.com%3E) from someone that was running into similar errors, and they suggested trying `nio` instead of `Netty`.

[SPARK-5085](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5085) is similar, in that changing from `Netty` to `nio` fixed their issue; however, they were also able to fix the issue by changing some networking settings. (I didn't try this yet myself, since I'm not sure I have the right access privileges to do so on the cluster.)

Comment: I am using spark version 1.4.1 and switching to nio solved the problem.

Comment: Using Spark 1.3.1 with HDP 2.3, we had the same problem. Switching to nio solved the problem.

Comment: switching to nio didn't solve the problem in spark 1.5.1, any idea?

Comment: I'm using spark 1.6.0 and switching to NIO still didnt solve the problem. I think this issue deserves a ticket as I see a large number of these errors in the logs.

Comment: I am using spark 2.0.0 and switching it to NIO still didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I am using spark 2.0.0 , got into the same problem. like @zahiro Mor , I tried the same but didnt work

Comment: @MeisamEmamjome I facing the issue. were you able to solve this?

Comment: @AnkushReddySugureddy I ended up repartitioning data and storing a smaller variation of it. The original data set contained a number of columns which I was not using. Also I think storing in parquet format was helpful as well as spark would be able to read relevant columns only and we have a chance for less data shuffling.

Comment: still having this issue in spark 2.2.0

Comment: According to the documentation regarding the setting spark.shuffle.blockTransferService : *Implementation to use for transferring shuffle and cached blocks between executors. There are two implementations available: netty and nio. Netty-based block transfer is intended to be simpler but equally efficient and is the default option starting in 1.2, and nio block transfer is deprecated in Spark 1.5.0 and will be removed in Spark 1.6.0.* And so I don't think it would resolve the issue to switch to nio

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue on 2.2.0.  Anyone found a fix?

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible that your Maven config is different from your Spark server installation.

For example your picked a pom.xml from an blog post Tutorial

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_1.3</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

But you could have downloaded the **latest 2.3** version on Apache Spark website.